# How can I make sticky header in Vuetify table?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I want to make sticky header, I've tried "**fixed:true**" it doesn't work.
When I scrolling table, action column's header isn't fixed, I've marked it on screenshot.

This is my table tag :

```
 <v-data-table
    :headers="headers"
    :items="rooms"
    sort-by="calories"
    class="elevation-1"
    fix-header
  >
```

and this is my headers data: 
headers: [{ text: "test", value: "action",fixed:true},
          { text: "test1", value: "action"}]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please provide your source code :>

Comment: No it's not duplicate.

Comment: Why would you ever want to make a table's header sticky? Normally you'll only want to make the navbar header sticky, and if that's the case, @PatelPratik mentioned the solution, but it seems it's not what you want.

Comment: @Reimond, its `fixed-header` not `fix-header`

Answer (score 5):

The `fixed-header` property only works if table height is defined.

I wrote a little article explaining my solution to this problem using position: sticky: https://medium.com/@jareklipski/sticky-table-header-in-vuetify-js-fab39988dc3

The overall idea is to set the  position to sticky and top value to 0 (or height of your fixed site header). Only one obstacle is that Vuetify.js data table has overflow, which can be addressed by /deep/ selector:

```
    .v-data-table /deep/ .v-data-table__wrapper {
        overflow: unset;
    }
```

Here's a complete working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/sticky-vuetify-table-header-3o0km

Answer (score 0):

Try using `position: fixed` as shown below:

```
.v-data-table .v-data-table__wrapper table thead tr {
      position: fixed;
}
```